# The correct place to implode array - MVC and Repositories concept

Tags: php, mvc, repository, laravel

I am writing an application with the repositories concept in php with laravel framework.
In my controller I have this method:

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 * PUT /locais/{id}
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    $data = Input::all();
    $data['str_categories'] = implode(',', $data['categories']);
    $this->place->update($id, $data);

    return Redirect::route('locais.index');
}
```

I am concerned about this line in controller:
`$data['str_categories'] = implode(',', $data['categories']);`

This line can be in controller method? Or this is a responsibility of places repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logic or data transformation should usually be moved out of the controller.  Your places repository seems like a better choice for the `implode`.  After all, one of the major purposes of repositories is to decouple data handling and storage as much as possible from other parts of the application, including controller.s